# getElementById : IE Issues

Tags: javascript

Having a problem with `document.getElementById` in IE 11 to retrive a `div`  who has a long url as id.

Example :

```
<div id="http://localhost:8084/group/control_panel/manage?p_auth=2kVqRblu&p_p_id=swcportaluploadData_WAR_swcportaluploadDataportlet&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&doAsGroupId=20182&refererPlid=20185&controlPanelCategory=current_site.content&_swcportaluploadData_WAR_swcportaluploadDataportlet_javax.portlet.action=loadCsvData&_swcportaluploadData_WAR_swcportaluploadDataportlet_fileName=CIS_Contact.xlsx"></div>
```

I am getting a null, but the id is unique. 
Works as expected on Google Chrome.

Where is the fault ? Special characters?

PS: It works fine for a simple id : `<div id="hello">`

Comment: As you'll see in that other question, HTML4 does not allow slashes to be in IDs. IE11 probably still enforces this restriction on IDs.

Comment: Have you considered using "normal" IDs and putting the URLs in `data-` attributes?

Comment: @PaulAbbott is `data` valid attribute for a `div` tag?

Comment: @joeyrohan Yes it is, the data-* attribute is a global attribute in html5

Comment: No, `data-`, as in `data-whatever-name-i-want` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML4 doesn't allow slashed as mentioned in this definition:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

IE still enforces that standard.

If you want to use the url, rather store the url in a `data-url` attribute.